# iOS CGColor versus UIColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I am using 2 variations of the same color, a light and dark version, to create a gradient.

Code:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

UIColor *light = [baseColor lightVersion];

UIColor *dark = [baseColor darkVersion];

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[light CGColor], (id)[dark CGColor], nil];
```

The problem is, I noticed that the `CGColor` version of the original `UIColor` version is different. Why is that? What is the difference between the `UIColor` and `CGColor` and why are they different?

Comment: Maybe some gamma correction issue.

Answer (score 25):

`UIColor` inherits from `NSObject` and is associated with `UIKit Framework` while `CGColor` is associated with `CoreGraphics` and `CGColor` is derived from `CFType`.

So if you are using UIKit elements then you can use `UIColor`, But if you are using drawing using Core Graphics or working with `CALayer` you must use `CGColor`.

As per Documentation of [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Many methods in UIKit require you to specify color data using a
> UIColor object, and for general color needs it should be your main way
> of specifying colors. The color spaces used by this object are
> optimized for use on iOS-based devices and are therefore appropriate
> for most drawing needs. **If you prefer to use Core Graphics colors and
> color spaces instead, however, you may do so.**

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question, I tried a sample project in which I took a label with a background color having RGB values (100,100,100). And set its border color to same RGB values but it is CGColor but I found no difference in them. Refer attached image. Border width is 5 pixels.[image: Label with same background color and border color]

Answer (score 0):

`UIColor` is just an Objective-C object wrapper of the C object `CGColor`. There should be no difference.

Answer (score -26):

There is no difference between *UIColour* and *CGColour*.

Comment: That's ridiculous.