# Why are there several color types in Swift? UIColor vs CGColor vs CIColor

Tags: swift, uicolor, cgcolor

I'm finding it difficult to find information as to *why* we have several Color classes in Swift/Objective C. Why not one unified class?

Comment: good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140576/ios-cgcolor-versus-uicolor

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that Q/A. Interesting. No mention of CIColor, but I get the idea - they're part of different frameworks and I guess a unified class wasn't an option.

Comment: It's not so much that as different frameworks evolving for different needs.  CGColor came first with Core Graphics, but it was a C interface.  CIColor was built around CGColor to complement the Objective-C interface of CoreImage.  UIColor was also built, but much much later, around CGColor to better complement UIKit, but also to present a unified front of interface objects.  Otherwise, your question would be "why isn't there a UIColor in UIKit?"

Comment: Great response - I guess my question then is that if CGColor came first, why not use it within CoreImage and UIKit to represent colors? Why create more Color classes? Or if CGColor didn't have the complete functionality required, why not extend it?

Comment: Because CGColor is a C interface, and CoreImage and UIKit being ObjC interfaces would probably rather work with ObjC objects. In Swift they're all presented as objects, but Swift wasn't around when CoreImage and UIKit were first designed.